# Creating link in Ckeditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

What am I doing wrong with this plugin?

```
editor.model.schema.register('section', {
    allowAttributes: ['class']
});
editor.model.schema.register('a', {
    allowAttributes: ['class', 'href', 'target', 'download']
});

editor.model.change(writer => {

    const section = writer.createElement('section', {
        class: 'button'
    });
    const link = writer.createElement('a', {
        href: 'https://dominio.com/file.pdf',
        target: '_blank',
        download: 'file.pdf'
    });

    writer.appendText('DOWNLOAD', link);
    writer.insert(link, section);

    editor.model.insertContent(section, editor.model.document.selection);

});
```

The result is being:

```
<p>DOWNLAOD</p>
```

But it should be:

```
<section class="button"><a href="https://dominio.com/file.pdf" download="file.pdf" targert="_blank">DOWNLOAD</a></section>
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong in creating this plugin on ckeditor 5?

Comment: I'm having the same difficulty, did you manage to solve it? If so, could you please share?

Comment: @WedsonQuintanilhadaSilva, hi brother, how are you?
I didn't decide how I would like to, but I did it like this:

`const link = writer.createText('DOWNLOAD', {
    linkHref: file
});

editor.model.insertContent(link, editor.model.document.selection);`

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't resolve it as I would like, but I did it like this:

```
editor.model.change(writer => {
  const link = writer.createText('DOWNLOAD', {
    linkHref: 'https://file_link'
  });

  editor.model.insertContent(link, editor.model.document.selection);
});
```

Comment: this doesn't include target=_blank, any possible way to add it?

Comment: @Kasun, I couldn't place the target, if you can, send it here to us.